# How can I save values from ratingBar in a database and show the mean of all values in a another ratingBar with the vote total?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I already created register and login activities. When a user enters in the main activity, I want to show them a ratingBar made up of five stars (similar to the Play Store).

When the user votes, the value of ratingBar should be saved in my database in a different table than the register table.

This is my rating.java:

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.RatingBar;

   import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
   import com.android.volley.Response;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import static com.lbstudios.*******.R.id.getRating;

   public class rating extends Activity {
RatingBar et_getRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(getRating);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
    final float getRating = Float.parseFloat(et_getRating.toString());
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(rating.this, MainActivity.class);
                    rating.this.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(rating.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    RateRequest rateRequest = new RateRequest(getRating, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(rating.this);
    queue.add(rateRequest);
}}
```

This is my activity_rating.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/getRating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my RateRequest.java:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RateRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String RATE_REQUEST_URL = "https://lbstudios.000webhostapp.com/Rate.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RateRequest(float getRating, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, RATE_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("rate", getRating + "");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

And this is my Rate.php:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("*****", "******", "*****", "******");

$rate = $_POST["rate"];
 function registerUser() {
    global $connect, $rate;
    //$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO rate1 (rate) VALUES (?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $rate); //$passwordHash);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;      
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

My table in the database is called rate1 and it's made up of one float column.

Comment: This question seems a little broad to me. You should break the problem down into steps: How do you get the user's rating? How do you send the rating to the DB? How do you get the average? etc.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now I ask a question at a time and hope someone help me.